# How to make dynamic phone number clickable for mobile users

Tags: javascript, html, phone-number, clickable

I have phone numbers on my website that are automatically inserted via a JavaScript to display either a default phone number (that's defined within the primary JavaScript) or change to a variable phone number if the webpage is accessed by a URL string with the phone number in it - for example:

```
http:www.website.com?tfid=8005551212
```

What I need to do is make the phone numbers clickable for mobile users so that whichever phone number appears they can click it and it will call the phone number.

I understand that if you wrap the phone number with an anchor with the tel: attribute it will launch the click-to-call function, but how can the tag be written so it will allow for the phone number variable to be passed? ex:

```
<a href="tel:variable telephone number">variable telephone number</a>
```

Comment: I've removed the javascipt code (which was added to assist anybody who would need to see how it added the variable), but do you have a recommendation on how to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?
Please rewrite your script to not use document.write. If you ever call one of your functions after the page loaded it will wipe the page.

```
document.getElementById("phonenumber").innerHTML='<a href="tel:'+phone_number+'">'+phone_number+'</a>';
```

Like this, using your original code

```
<div id="phonenumber">Call:  </div>
```

---

```
function getPhone() {
   var phone = get_named_cookie("MM_TrackableNumber");
   if (phone == null) phone = "8885551313";
   return formatnumber(phone);
}

window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("phonenumber").innerHTML+=getPhone();
}
```

---

Full code

```
   function pixelfire(debug) {
       var phone_number = getVar("phone_number");
       var keyword = getVar("keyword");
       var source = getVar("source");
       if (keyword) {
           setcookie(keyword, phone_number);
       } else {
           var keyword = get_named_cookie("MM_Keyword");
           var phone_number = get_named_cookie("MM_TrackableNumber");
           return keyword || null;
       }
       var campaign = getVar("campaign");
       var content = getVar("content");
       var url = "http://www.mongoosemetrics.com/pixelfire.php?phone_number=" + phone_number;
       var url = url + "&keyword=" + keyword;
       var url = url + "&source=" + source;
       var url = url + "&campaign=" + campaign;
       var url = url + "&content=" + content;
       myImage = new Image();
       myImage.src = url;
   }

   function setcookie(key, tn, path) {
       index = -1;
       var today = new Date();
       today.setTime(today.getTime());
       var cookie_expire_date = new Date(today.getTime() + (365 * 86400000));
       document.cookie = "MM_TrackableNumber=" + tn + ";path=/;expires=" + cookie_expire_date.toGMTString();
       document.cookie = "MM_Keyword=" + key + ";path=/;expires=" + cookie_expire_date.toGMTString();
   }
   function getPhone() {
       var phone = get_named_cookie("MM_TrackableNumber");
       if (phone == null) phone = "8885551313";
       return formatnumber(phone);
   }

   function get_named_cookie(name) {
       if (document.cookie) {
           index = document.cookie.indexOf(name);
           if (index != -1) {
               namestart = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
               nameend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
               if (nameend == -1) {
                   nameend = document.cookie.length;
               }
               var ret_one = document.cookie.substring(namestart, nameend);
               return ret_one;
           }
       }
   }
   //function to format the phonenumber to (123) 456-7890
   function formatnumber(num) {
       _return = "1-";
       var ini = num.substring(0, 3);
       _return += ini + "-";
       var st = num.substring(3, 6);
       _return += st + "-";
       var end = num.substring(6, 10);
       _return += end;
       return _return;
   }

   function getVar(name) {
       get_string = document.location.search;
       return_value = '';

       do { //This loop is made to catch all instances of any get variable.
           name_index = get_string.indexOf(name + '=');

           if (name_index != -1) {
               get_string = get_string.substr(name_index + name.length + 1, get_string.length - name_index);

               end_of_value = get_string.indexOf('&');
               if (end_of_value != -1) value = get_string.substr(0, end_of_value);
               else value = get_string;

               if (return_value == '' || value == '') return_value += value;
               else return_value += ', ' + value;
           }
       } while (name_index != -1)

       //Restores all the blank spaces.
       space = return_value.indexOf('+');
       while (space != -1) {
           return_value = return_value.substr(0, space) + ' ' + return_value.substr(space + 1, return_value.length);

           space = return_value.indexOf('+');
       }

       return (return_value);
   }
   window.onload = function () {
       key = getVar("keyword");
       tn = getVar("tfid");
       source = getVar("source");
       content = getVar("content");
       campaign = getVar("campaign");
       if (tn != "") {
           setcookie(key, tn);
       }
       var phone_number = getPhone();
       document.getElementById("phonenumber").innerHTML+='<a href="tel:'+phone_number+'">'+phone_number+'</a>';
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I can't rewrite the javascript to remove the document.write function. Is there a way to add an onclick element to the href that would insert the phone number variable without rewriting the javascripts?

Comment: I really appreciate you for rewriting the javascript, but how can I make the anchor clickable with the dynamic element?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what I'm trying to do is insert the phone number from the javascript into the anchor tag so it makes it possible for the phone number to be clickable. ex: `<a href="tel:8885551313"><div id="phonenumber">Call:  </div></a>` The example shows how it would look with the default phone number (888-555-1313), but if somebody comes to the webpage through a URL string such as `http:www.website.com?tfid=8005551212` , it would replace the default number with the dynamic number following the tel: part of the anchor. ex: `<a href="tel:8005551212"><div id="phonenumber">Call:  </div></a>`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused with where the tel: element is added to make it clickable, but I've added the `<div id="phonenumber">Call:  </div>` code to my page and I'm not sure what to add either within it, or to wrap it with an anchor, but the div itself isn't clickable. What code am I missing?

Comment: I add the link to the div. I gave it an id because it is easier to access than the class you had on your existing div. just add the ID and the link is inserted. If there is no cookie or number in the Url,  default is used

Comment: So what you're saying is that I use the code like this: `<a id="phonenumber"><div id="phonenumber">Call: </div></a>` and this will allow it to be clickable by mobile users so that their phones will automatically dial the number if they click on it? Shouldn't the link have the tel: attribute that has the phone number within it? ex: `<a href="tel:" id="phonenumber"></a>`

Comment: So sorry! I was missing the link in the second part of my code. I have updated now

Comment: just got back and saw your comment, tried it and it worked!!!!!  mplungjan you are a genius!!! thank you so very much!!!